# Find documents by reference property (not id)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find all the products who belong to a category recived in an array, i.e.

I have this documents of category:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fa006c9e8c8633bd00dc9bf"),
    "name" : "Beer"
    "__v" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fa3f6a69a55a4294815d333"),
    "name" : "Gin"
    "__v" : 0
}
```

And three products like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc5ba87d5b8e358888e976f"),
    "code" : "CER473HEIN",
    "category" : ObjectId("5fa006c9e8c8633bd00dc9bf"),
    "__v" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6011e4d83408972b34fd048f"),
    "code" : "GIN700BEEF",
    "category" : ObjectId("5fa3f6a69a55a4294815d333"),
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6011e4f73408972b34fd0492"),
    "code" : "GIN700GORD",
    "category" : ObjectId("5fa3f6a69a55a4294815d333"),
}
```

If in the body of the request I send an array like this:

{ categories = ['Beer', 'Gin']` }

I want to get all three products but if I only send 'Beer' I want to get only the product with the category 'Beer'.

I was trying something like this in the service layer of Product:

```
let getProductsByCategories = (req, res) => {
    const { categories } = req.body; 
    Product.find({ 'category.name' : { $in: categories }})
        .exec((err, productos) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: 'Error interno en el servidor'
                });
            }
            if (!productos) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: {
                        message: 'No se encontraron productos.'
                    }
                });
            }

            res.json({
                ok: true,
                cantidad: productos.length,
                entidadResultante: productos
            });
        })
}
```

I.E:

But it always return 0 products with a category who was 6 products. Any idea why this is happening? Ty.

Comment: Instead of showing us schemas, why don you just show your sample docs and state precisely what you want the query to do.

Comment: I edited the answer, sorry. I hope that now u can understood. Ty!

Comment: `category.name` does not exist in Product records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can using populate if you used `ref` in schema, but without `ref` you should write two query, at first get list of Id's category based on `req.body.categories` after that you can get the list of products

```
 let getProductsByCategories = (req, res) => {
    const { categories } = req.body; 
    Category.find({ 'category.name' : { $in: categories }})
        .exec((err, categoryID) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: 'Error interno en el servidor'
                });
            }
            if (!categoryID) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: {
                        message: 'categoryID'
                    }
                });
            }
            let listOfIds = categoryID.map(item => item._id)
            Product.find({ 'category' : { $in: listOfIds }})
            .exec((err, productos) => {
                res.json({
                    ok: true,
                    cantidad: productos.length,
                    entidadResultante: productos
                });
            })

        })
}
```

if you are using ref in schema, just try like this:

```
  Product.find()
    .populate({
      path: "category",
      match: {
        "category.name": { $in: categories },
      },
    })
    .exec(function (err, productos) {
      console.log(productos);
    });
};
```

Comment: Ty! One question, I don't understand what you say at the end. Can u explain a little more that?

Comment: when you want use populate  so category: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "Category" }], after that you can use populate, check the https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html